# AS3. EventListener.Click depends on position

Tags: actionscript-3, events, click, event-listener

I'm doing a button on AS3 made out of a sprite wich (just a simple square). When I add the event listener so that it acts as a button it works but depending on button.x, so when I put the button where I want the button stops working.

Thanks

```
        public function pintaInterficieTrad(){

        while(numChildren != 0) removeChildAt(0);

        var idioma = new TextField();

        idioma.text=traductor.*[numTrad].*;
        idioma.width=200;
        idioma.selectable=false;
        idioma.setTextFormat(format);
        idioma.x=20;
        idioma.y=20;
        addChild(idioma);

        var trad = new Sprite();
        trad.graphics.lineStyle(5,0x00ff00);
        trad.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
        trad.graphics.drawRect(300,20,150,70);
        addChild(trad);

        var textTrad = new TextField();

        if(numTrad==0) {
            textTrad.text="Traduir";
        }else{
            textTrad.text="Traducir";
        }

        textTrad.width=200;
        textTrad.selectable=false;
        textTrad.setTextFormat(format);
        textTrad.x=270;
        textTrad.y=40;
        addChild(textTrad);

        var getBack = new Sprite();
        getBack.graphics.lineStyle(5,0x00ff00);
        getBack.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
        getBack.graphics.drawRect(500,20,150,70);
        addChild(getBack);

        var textgetBack = new TextField();
        if(numTrad==0) {
            textgetBack.text="Tornar";
        }else{
            textgetBack.text="Volver";
        }

        textgetBack.width=200;
        textgetBack.selectable=false;
        textgetBack.setTextFormat(format);
        textgetBack.x=470;
        textgetBack.y=40;
        addChild(textgetBack);

        trad.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,traduirBtn);
        getBack.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,tornarBtn);

        var userBox = new Sprite();
        userBox.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x00ff00);
        userBox.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff);
        userBox.graphics.drawRect(40,130,610,160);
        addChild(userBox);

        var tradBox = new Sprite();
        tradBox.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x00ff00);
        tradBox.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff);
        tradBox.graphics.drawRect(40,320,610,160);
        addChild(tradBox);      

        var formatTxt = new TextFormat();
        formatTxt.color=0x000000;
        formatTxt.size=14;


        var textUser = new TextField();
        var textTraduit = new TextField();

        textUser.defaultTextFormat=formatTxt;
        textUser.text = textUsuari;
        textUser.width = 600;
        textUser.height = 150;
        textUser.x=45;
        textUser.y=130;
        addChild(textUser);

        textTraduit.text = traduccio;
        textTraduit.setTextFormat(formatTxt);
        textTraduit.width = 600;
        textTraduit.height = 150;
        textTraduit.x=45;
        textTraduit.y=325;
        addChild(textTraduit);

    }

    public function traduirBtn(e){
        while(numChildren != 0) removeChildAt(0);
        tradueix();
        pintaInterficieTrad();
    }
    public function tornarBtn(e){
        while(numChildren != 0) removeChildAt(0);
        pintaMenu();
    }

}
```

If I put the squares on x=0 they do what they're suposed to do...

Comment: Please, post the relevant code. Also, are you using Flash or another IDE like FlashDevelop?

Comment: I'm using just Adobe Flash CS6. Posting code in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like the button you're talking about is `trad`. You're `addChild`ing it quite early in your code, which means that antoher displayobject could get above it at the same position. When you click at that position, the click event will only get send to the top most element, so try adding the elements you want people to interact with as the last (buttons, text field inputs, etc.)

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. I want to put a box (which is the button) and above a text. Can't I do that?

Comment: Never mind. It's solved as you said. Thanks. I just added the Child the latest I could

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the fact that you are adding the text over the button and the text is being clicked, not the button.

Add the text to the button itself and your click event will work.

Also verify that no other component is covering the button. Even if transparent, like a textbox.